# Why does changing working directory to desktop subfolder using environment variable UserProfile not work?

Tags: batch-file

I am making this code in batch, in which the directory needs to be changed in order for the commands to complete successfully. Right now, this is what I've discerned to use, from other posts asking the same question:

```
cd C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Desktop\NewFolder
```

From what I read, this should work, but it isn't. And I don't know why.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `HELP SET` and then try `SET user` and you will realize that USERPROFILE contains the **full path** of the current user home directory.

So, to set the current working directory to the user desktop, you need to either

```
CD /D %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

or

```
PUSHD %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

which is better, because you may later `POPD` to restore the current directory to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\NewFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\NewFolder"`

Environment variable **USERPROFILE** contains full path to the profile directory of the current user. The user name stored in environment variable **USERNAME** which is included also in **USERPROFILE** can contain also 1 or more spaces and therefore it is better to use double quotes around complete path.

And the user's profile directory can be on a different drive as the current drive. So it is better to use also parameter `/D` on changing the current directory.

By the way: Executing in a new command prompt window the command `set` shows all standard environment variables with their current values.